# Class appears to be loaded from different NSBundle in tests after updating Cocoapods gem, resulting in nil singleton

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, nsbundle

I'm using RestKit in my application, setting it up in the AppDelegate. I have some unit tests that depend on the `RKObjectManager` singleton. This is set up in the AppDelegate. Some tests set up a managed object store specifically for the tests, as below. Others call `getObject` etc on it directly to test response mappings.

This is in my test `setUp`:

```
RKObjectManager *mgr = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[mgr setManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
```

This has been working successfully for a long time.

I recently updated my Cocoapods gem from `0.33.1` to the latest (`0.38.2` right now), and now, in the above example `mgr` is `nil`. If I drop a breakpoint on the second line above, the `sharedManager` clearly returns a non-nil value, yet my local variable is nil:

```
(lldb) po mgr
 nil
(lldb) po [RKObjectManager sharedManager]
<RKObjectManager: 0x7fe9e2d1d5e0>
```

I suspect I have, effectively, two copies of `RKObjectManager` loaded at runtime (once from the app bundle and once from the test bundle). I've [tried all the solutions listed here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1411), but the comment of interest [talks about how each target gets its own copy of the class](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1411#issuecomment-37329319). Indeed, if I override the `+(void) load` method on `RKObjectManager`, it gets called twice.

If I store a reference to the shared manager as a property on my AppDelegate, then I can retrieve the shared instance from that successfully - just not from the class method as above. I'd rather not repeat this work-around across all my tests.

How can I configure Cocoapods to link the "right" version of RKObjectManager with my tests, so I can retrieve the shared instance directly once more?

My podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Closeout' do
    pod 'RestKit'
    ... some other pods
end

target 'CloseoutTests' do
    pod 'RestKit/Testing'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
end
```

Edit: I have a workaround that's certainly better than exposing a property on the AppDelegate simply for the benefit of testing, but I'd still like to know how to avoid doing this:

```
AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate*)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate);
NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[delegate class]];
id objMgr = [appBundle classNamed:@"RKObjectManager"];
[[objMgr sharedManager] setManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaPods changed the way dependencies are added in version 0.36 - [the release blog has a very good explanation of why this is necessary](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/), but the general idea is that it was required for Swift support.

I added the following keyword, introduced in CocoaPods 0.36 to my Podfile:

`use_frameworks!`

I removed my targets and used `link_with` instead, so my Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

link_with 'Closeout', 'CloseoutTests'
use_frameworks!

pod 'RestKit'
pod 'RestKit/Testing'
pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
... other pods
```

Additionally, I had to ensure I was running RestKit 0.25 or higher, as that [includes this PR](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/2145), enabling support for Frameworks.

`pod 'RestKit', '0.25.0'`

Finally, I had to fix a bunch of compilation errors:

`#import <RestKit.h>` became `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>`